# Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 when deploying hyperledger fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using tensorflow nodejs in a chaincode, the chaincode deploys successfully, but when I try t query it, the following error show up:

```
Error: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/src/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8/../../deps/lib/libtensorflow.so.2)
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1338:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js:72:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

I have `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` added to my PATH, but didn't work.